# How to map three Websites under one domain to their folders with mod_rewrite only?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, splash-screen, subdirectory

I have a project that has a splash page that points to two separate sites. The sites are hosted on the same server and they should be in separate folders for better maintenance.

The folder structure should be something like this:

```
/home/user1234/public_html

    /splash/
        index.html
        css/
        images/
        ...

    /site1/
        index.php
        css/
        images/
        ...

    /site2/
        index.php
        css/
        images/
        ...
```

The main sites (site1 and site2, probably two Wordpress installs) have to be accessible under a sub-directory like url structure, NOT sub-domains! So the url structure should be:

```
www.MySite.tld --> Splash
www.MySite.tld/site1 --> Site1
www.MySite.tld/site2 --> Site2
```

Now I have to match these urls to their corresponding directory on the server. But I don't know exactly how to do this.
I have to say that it's a shared hosting server, so I can only use htaccess and mod_rewrite to accomplish this, right?

So, in the webhost's admin interface I pointed www.MySite.tld to the /splash folder. Then I put the .htaccess in that folder and rewrite requests to the "virtual folder" /site1 and /site2, something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(site1|site2)/?$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/user1234/public_html/%1 [L]
```

This doesn't work because, as far as I know, one can't rewrite to files outside the current DOCUMENT_ROOT (/splash) with mod_rewrite only. So I tried to point www.MySite.tld one level up to /public_html instead of /splash. Now requests to /site1 and /site2 work for sure but request to / returns a 404 on default because there is no index file in there as you can see in the folder structure above. So I also put the .htaccess one level up in /public_html with the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /splash [L]
```

Now the splash page is accessable but that appends a "/splash" at the end of the url what I don't want!

I have been searching for a solution for many hours and tried many of the suggestions I found so far, but none of these solved my problem. Last thing I tried was to set up some [virtual host with mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/vhosts.html), but I couldn't get that to work too. Probably I'm just not confirm enough yet with mod_rewrite and all this other apache stuff. ;-)

Or maybe I am missing just something fundamental like setting a correct RewriteBase...Can this url + folder structure be accomplished at all with mod_rewrite only? If yes, what rewrite rules do I have to set? If not, are there any alternatives I can use? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: might be worth migrating this to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can quite easily accomplish this with mod_rewrite. Given the URL structure you outlined, use the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(site1|site2|splash)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) splash/$1 [L,PT]
```

The `RewriteCond` will avoid rewrites when site1 or site2 is requested, and also prevents infinite loops on requests to `/splash` (this is especially crucial with .htaccess implementation).

If `RewriteCond` is a match (i.e. request is not for any of the three paths) `RewriteRule` is matched against all URLs `^(.*)` and rewritten as `splash/$1`. The options `L,PT` define that this should be the `L|last` rule (useful in VirtualHost context, doesn't always work in .htaccess) and that the request should `PT|passthrough` to the backend (in this case Apache, again), without sending a redirect (30x) header to the client browser.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful, especially the thing with `PT|passthrough` - didn't know about that flag.
Now it works and it was really quite easy in the end...
Thank you so much!